# condition for which we have an integrable function

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $\Omega=[-L,L] \subset \mathbb{R}$, and let $n=\dfrac{u_x}{|u_x|}$. Now my question is what are the conditions on $\gamma(n)$ and $u_x$ so that we have

$$\gamma^2(n) u_x \in L^1$$

i.e. $\gamma^2(n) u_x$ integrable.

where $\gamma$ is any function as general as we can take it.

Comment: are you assuming $u_x$ (is that the $x$ derivative of $u$?) is already in $L^1$?

Comment: $u_x(x,t)$ is the partial derivative of $u(x,t)$ w.r.t. $x$

Answer (score 0):

If we assume $u_x\in L^1(\Omega)$, then if we assertain the assumption that $|\gamma(\pm 1)|\leq K$ for some $K$ finite, then:

$\int_\Omega|\gamma^2(n)u_x|dx=\int_{-L}^{L}|\gamma^2(\pm1)||u_x|dx\leq K^2\int_{-L}^{L}|u_x|dx\lt\infty$, thus then $\gamma^2(n)u_x\in L^1(\Omega)$

Equivalently, since $\Omega=[-L,L]$ where $L$ is finite, then $u_x\in L^1$ if it is bounded.